# Changing background image jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a script that changes the background color of the div when a file is dragged over it, however I would like to change it so that the background image changes e.g.An image with the world 'Drop your file'

Here is the code I have to work with so far.

```
function dragover(e)
{
   e.stopPropagation(); 
   e.preventDefault();

f('.dropable').css({
    backgroundColor : 'rgb(51, 51, 51)',
    border : 0,
});
```

}

I have tried, but it didn't seem to work.

```
function dragover(e)
{
e.stopPropagation(); 
e.preventDefault();

f('.dropable').css({
    backgroundColor : 'rgb(51, 51, 51)',
    border : 0,
    backgroundImage','url(uploadimg.png)
});
}
```

Comment: you have 2 added commas after backgroundImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of a classname (e.g. `dragover`) and [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

```
​.dragover {
    background-color : rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0;
    background-image: url(uploadimg.png);
}​
```

```
var dragover = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    f(".dropable").addClass("dragover");
}​
```

I don't know why are you using `f(...)`, but I left it as is. Normally, I would use `$(...)`.

---

Having said that if you still want to go with `.css()`. You can do it using the following syntax:

```
var dragover = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    f(".dropable").css({
        backgroundColor: "rgb(51, 51, 51)",
        border: 0,
        backgroundImage: "url(uploadimg.png)"
    });
}
```